# Recursive Loop for Generic Tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, depth-first-search

for days I am now trying to solve the following problem. A recursive function is suppose to iterate through a dictionary that is basically a representation of a tree.

The input looks like this:

```
var connections = {1:[2, 3, 4], 2:[5, 6, 7], 3:[8], 4:[9, 10]}
```

and the corresponding tree that it represents looks like this:

[image: tree represented by the dictionary 'connections']

The intermediate goal is to print out the numbers in a depht first search manner, namely:

[image: how the result should look like]

My solution for this problem is:

```
function dfs(connections, parent) {
    console.log(parent);
    if (!(parent in connections)) {
      return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < connections[parent].length; i++) {
      dfs(connections, connections[parent][i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

However, calling the function

```
dfs(connections, 1)
```

leads to the following result:

```
1
2
5
6
7
```

That means it is not returning to the previous function and continuing the for-loop. If you have any idea whatsoever, I would be very grateful.

Cheers

Comment: You need to start by property declaring the variable in the loop: `for (let i = 0; i < connections[parent].length; i++)` Otherwise you are declaring a global and it's getting clobbered on recursion.

Comment: please close the question, because of the global use of `i`.

Comment: Thanks for editing the post @NinaScholz. After posting I was looking for how to display the images in the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `i` is implicitly global, so after it iterates through `2` (which has a length of 3), `i` is 4, so further tests of `i < connections[parent].length` fail.

You could use `let` to fix it (`for (let i = 0`), but it would probably be better to use `forEach` instead: array methods are less verbose, less error-prone, and more functional than `for` loops:

```js
var connections = {
  1: [2, 3, 4],
  2: [5, 6, 7],
  3: [8],
  4: [9, 10]
}

function dfs(connections, parent) {
  console.log(parent);
  if (!(parent in connections)) {
    return;
  }
  connections[parent].forEach(prop => dfs(connections, prop));
}
dfs(connections, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the fix! That helps me to improve in Js.